# Why sometimes Laravel API return 404 error on fetch Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-7

I'm currently making application with these spesifications:

1. Back-end: Laravel 7+
2. Front-end: Vue.js
3. Local Development Pack: Laragon, with local SSL enabled

And I've been using some free template based on bootstrap as well.

So here's the deal, each time I make some fetch() API request from the Vue.js side (front-end side), I noticed that out of 100 attempt, roughly 6 of them return 404.

My API is on ```Route::prefix('api')``` and I guess there is nothing wrong with the CORS, etc.

I don't know if this is a big deal, but I hesitate to continue on with this method of getting data until I figure out what is actually going on with the request and fetch, since 6 / 100 chance is actually quite scary for me, considering the functionality of the App that I'm currently building.

I don't know if my description is enough, but if it isn't, then feel free to yell at me so that I could make it even deeper.

And... If any of you ask what I've tried to fix this, to be true I don't really know what should I do. I think the only thing I tried was to look for an answer in here and learned that no one ever face similar issue.

Cheers.

Edit:
Case closed. It was definitely because of the throttle limit. Count it myself, as I went to the 61st request, the 404 is thrown. Big thanks.

Edit:
Shoot! It is **still a problem**. And I've noticed that throttle problem should've return 429. My API return 404. Any idea why guys? I've disabled the throttle in Kernel. But funny thing is, I've tried deploying it on my VPS and it works perfectly. Is the problem on my local server or what?

[image: Network]

Comment: maybe you hit throttle limit (wich by default is 60 per minute)

Comment: Interesting lad. But the way I refresh it is only for like twice per minute, but in a smaller gap. Let's say I hit F5, I raise the finger a little bit, then I hit it again. So it was like half second or something. Is that relevant to the throttle?

Comment: depends on how many request you run on each refresh. anyway you can check out the header reponse when the request fails on the network tab

Comment: I've checked it and it return NotFoundHttpException. But again, sometimes it's found

Answer (score 0):

You are reaching maximum trottle rate. The default throttle limits it to 60 attempts per minute.To Track throttle look at the response header. for example if you have route like the following

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => 'throttle'], function () {
    Route::get('people', function () {
        return Person::all();
    });
});
```

viewing the response header will reveal the throttle info like

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
... other headers here ...
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
```

Remember, this response means:

- A) This request succeeded (the status is 200)
- B) You can try this    route 60 times per minute
- C) You have 59 requests left for this    minute

What response would we get if we went over the rate limit?

```
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
... other headers here ...
Retry-After: 60
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
```

**Customizing the `throttle` middleware**

The `throttle` middleware accepts two parameters that determine the maximum number of requests that can be made in a given number of minutes. For example, let's specify that an authenticated user may access the following group of routes 60 times per minute:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:60,1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function () {
        //
    });
});
```

you if you want to allow making more that 60 request per min to the route change the throttle first param

```
Route::middleware('auth:api', 'throttle:100,1')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', function () {
        //
    });
});
```

Comment: But I swear it didn't return 429. It returns 404. I've disabled the throttle and it still returns 404 sometimes. It trully frustrate me.